# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values' of nested dictionary from XML

Tags: python, json, xml, dataframe, dictionary

I have a source from xml file and then I converted to `dict` looks like this :

```
data= {
  "Head": {
    "@xmlns": "http://www...",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www...",
    "@xsi:schemaLocation": "http://www...",
    "Header": {
      "Num": " ",
      "Type": {
        "source": "user",
        "text": "Training"
      },
      "FNum": "SSSSS",
      "FDate": "2020-10-02T04:30:00Z",
      "From": "ABC",
      "To": "DEF",
      "AC": "AAAA",
      "Reg": "BBBB"
    },
    "AdditionalComment": " ", #Cause of problem!
    "Period": {
      "Duration": " ",
      "LOL": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

Originally in xml, it looks like this (I can't change them) :

```
.....
  <Header>
             ......
  </Header>
    <AdditionalComment/> # Focus here
    <Period>
        <Duration/>
        <LOL>false</LOL>
    </Period>
</Head>
```

My code works perfectly if I exclude `AdditionalComment` but I can't exclude them for some reasons. However, I will get this error if I INCLUDE `AdditionalComment`:

> ```
> if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data): AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
> ```

at `pd.json_normalize`. I've tested by replace values, also does not work.

Below is my current codes:

```
# Replacing None to other values
def replaceNone(data_dict,v,rv):
    for key1 in data_dict.keys():
        if data_dict[key1] == v:
            data_dict[key1] = rv
        elif type(data_dict[key1]) is dict:
            replaceNone(data_dict[key1],v,rv)


with open('test_file.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

    data = json.dumps(doc)
    data = json.loads(data)
    replaceNone(data,None," ")

# Get list of key for next iteration
key_list = []
for l_key, l_value in data.items():
        
    for n_key, n_value in l_value.items():
            
        # Exclude unnecessary key from the list
        if n_key == '@xmlns' or n_key == '@xmlns:xsi' or n_key == '@xsi:schemaLocation' or n_key == 'AdditionalComment':
                continue
        else:
            key_list.append(n_key)
        
    
# Join flatten dictionary to a new dataframe
for key, value in data.items():
    k = 0
    for idx in key_list:
        data_df = pd.json_normalize(data[key][idx]) #HITTING ERROR HERE
        if k==0:
            final_df = data_df
        else:
            final_df = final_df.join(data_df, lsuffix='_left')
        k += 1
```